# Printing on a PC - Can I set up multiple profiles for the same printer?

Tags: printer, printing

I'm setting up printing on a PC with Internet Explorer. I want to be able to easily toggle between one print profile (which uses Tray 1) and another print profile (which uses Tray 2).

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Install a new printer, use the existing port the printer uses, when it asks to "use the same driver?"  tell it YES for sure, you do not want to have to put on another wad of drivers.  After you get the second profile for the printer created, go into the properties and change the friendly name for the printer. Get into the "printer properties" not the normal properties, check the port in the "ports" tab, and set the "printing Defaults" in the advanced tab.

Comment: Yep, I do this all the time with color printers, so one can use B&W or color without having to change the profiles.

Comment: @opsin Does this work in Windows 10, and do you happen to know how to do it for Wi-Fi HP printers?